# Postfix: multiple aliases for same mail address from multiple results

Tags: postfix, alias

I am about to configure our new mailserver and one feature must be that mailinglists must be delivered to multiple receipients as well as to an internal shared imap folder.

we store most of our users and configuration in a ldap directory.
every user has an attribute if and where mailinglists should be forwarded to as well as a list of which entries should be forwarded.

so when I query for a mail address in postfix in the alias map, multiple results would be found (for every user that wants to receive this mail).

is this possible?